# Converting this format: 40 mile air q5 to: [ '40 Mile Air', 'Q5' ] (in js)

Tags: javascript, string, list

I think I have a relatively simple question, but somehow I've been working on it the whole morning without result.

I have a list (http://www.avrefdesk.com/two_letter_airline_codes.htm) of data which I want to convert with javascript to another format [ '40 Mile Air', 'Q5' ].

I tried excel, but that didn't work out. Looked at other topcis here but wasn't able to find it.

This is the script I've been using.

```
var list = ["40 Mile Air Q5",
            "AB Airlines 7L",
            "ABSA Cargo - Aerolinhas Breseleiras SA M3",
            "AccessAir ZA",
            "ACES Colombia VX"];

var newList = list.map(function(e, i) {
                          return [e.slice(0, -3), e.slice(-2)];
                        });
console.log(newList);
```

Please help me out, if there are things that aren't clear; let me know.

Comment: That page is a 404, please include relevant information in your question, plus some of your attempts that you've been working on so we can help you fix them, rather than writing an entire solution from scratch.

Comment: ai sorry James, 

i ll add the script i've made a little progress with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var l=[["40 Mile Air","Q5"],["AB Airlines","7L"],["ABSA Cargo - Aerolinhas Breseleiras SA","M3"],["AccessAir","ZA"],["ACES Colombia","VX"],["Action Airlines","XQ"],["Acvilla Air - Aor Romanian Carrier","WZ"],["Ade Air Albania","ZY"],["Adria Airways","JP"],["Advance Leasing","4G"],["Aer Arann","RE"],["Aer Lingus","EI"],["Aero Asia International","E4"],["Aero Continente","N6"],["Aero Contractors Company of Nigeria - ACN","NU"],["Aero Lloyd","YP"],["Aero Santa","UJ"],["Aero Services Executive","W4"],["Aero Zambia","Z9"],["Aerocalifornia","JR"],["Aerocaribe","QA"],["Aerocondor","P2"],["Aeroexo - Aero Ejectivo","SX"],["Aeroflot Russian International Airlines","SU"],["Aerolineas Argentinas","AR"],["Aerolineas Internacionales","N2"],["Aerolineas Santo Domingo","EX"],["Aerolineas Sosa","P4"],["AeroLyon","4Q"],["Aeromar","BQ"],["Aeromar Airlines","VW"],["Aeromexico","AM"],["Aeromexpress","QO"],["Aeroperlas (Apair - Aerolineas Pacificio Atlantico)","WL"],["Aeroperu","PL"],["Aeropostal","VH"],["Aerorepublica Colombia","P5"],["Aeroservice","BF"],["Aerosucre","6N"],["Aerosur","5L"],["Aerosweet Airlines","VV"],["Affertair","ZL"],["Africa West","3L"],["African International Airways","OY"],["Aiborne of Sweden","ZF"],["Aipac Airlines","LQ"],["Air 2000","DP"],["Air Afrique","RK"],["Air Alaska Cargo","8S"],["Air Alfa","H7"],["Air Algerie","AH"],["Air Alliance","3J"],["Air Anatolia","TD"],["Air Aruba","FQ"],["Air Asia","AK"],["Air Atlanta - Atlanta Icelandic Air Transport","CC"],["Air Atlantic","9A"],["Air Atlantic Dominicana","LU"],["Air Atlantic Spain","QD"],["Air Austral","UU"],["Air Baltic","BT"],["Air BC","ZX"],["Air Belgium International","AJ"],["Air Berlin","AB"],["Air Bosna","JA"],["Air Botnia","KF"],["Air Botswana","BP"],["Air Burkina","2J"],["Air Caledonie","TY"],["Air Caledonie International","SB"],["Air Canada","AC"],["Air Caraibes","WS"],["Air Cargo Express","3K"],["Air Carribean","C2"],["Air Carribean - CLTM Airlines","XC"],["Air Chathams","CV"],["Air China","CA"],["Air City","4F"],["Air Comet","2Z"],["Air Contracors","AG"],["Air Creebec","YN"],["Air d'Ayiti","2N"],["Air Direct","C7"],["Air Djibouti - Red Sea Airlines","DY"],["Air Dolomiti","EN"],["Air East Africa","K5"],["Air Europa","UX"],["Air Europe Italy","PE"],["Air Facilities","FZ"],["Air Fiji (Fiji Air Services)","PC"],["Air Florida Express","FD"],["Air Foyle","GS"],["Air France","AF"],["Air Gabon","GN"],["Air Georgia","DA"],["Air Glaciers","GB"],["Air Greece","JG"],["Air Guadeloupe","TX"],["Air Holland","GG"],["Air Hong Kong","LD"],["Air Iceland - Flugfelag Islands","NY"],["Air India","AI"],["Air Inuit","3H"],["Air ivoire","VU"],["Air Jamaica","JM"],["Air Jet","BC"],["Air Kazakstan","9Y"],["Air Kenya Aviation","QP"],["Air Koryo","JS"],["Air Labrador - Labrador Airways","WJ"],["Air Lanka","UL"],["Air Liberte","IJ"],["Air Link","DR"],["Air Lithuania - Aviakompanija Lietuva","TT"],["Air Littoral","FU"],["Air Macau","NX"],["Air Madagascar","MD"],["Air Malawi","QM"],["Air Maldives","L6"],["Air Mali","L9"],["Air Malta","KM"],["Air mandalay","6T"],["Air Marshall Islands","CW"],["Air Mauritanie","MR"],["Air Mauritius","MK"],["Air Moldova","9U"],["Air Moldova International","3R"],["Air Montreal","F8"],["Air Namibia","SW"],["Air Nauru","ON"],["Air Negril","5T"],["Air New Zealand","NZ"],["Air New Zealand Link / Mount Cook Airlines","NM"],["Air Nippon","EL"],["Air Niugini","PX"],["Air North Charter","4N"],["Air North Regional","TL"],["Air Nostrum","YW"],["Air Nova","QK"],["Air One","9Q"],["Air One","AP"],["Air Ontario","GX"],["Air Orient","UT"],["Air Ostrava","8K"],["Air Pacific","FJ"],["Air Philippines","2P"],["Air Plus","OB"],["Air Provence Interionational","DG"],["Air Roratonga","GZ"],["Air Routing International","ZJ"],["Air Saint Barthelemy (Barths Aviation)","OJ"],["Air Saint Martin","S6"],["Air Saint Pierre","PJ"],["Air Saint Thomas","ZP"],["Air Seychelles","HM"],["Air Sicilia","BM"],["Air Sinai","4D"],["Air Slovakia","GM"],["Air Sofia","CT"],["Air Stord","GO"],["Air Sultan","0O"],["Air Sunshine","YI"],["Air Tahiti","VT"],["Air Tahiti NUI","TN"],["Air Tanzania","TC"],["Air Team","8W"],["Air Toulouse International","SH"],["Air Transat","TS"],["Air Transport International - ATI","8C"],["Air Trindi","8T"],["Air Ukraine - Avialinii Ukrainy","6U"],["Air Urga","3N"],["Air Vallee","DO"],["Air Vanuatu","NF"],["Air Vegas","6V"],["Air Virginia","DO"],["Air Wings","XR"],["Air Zambezi","ZT"],["Air Zena","A9"],["Air Zimbabwe","UM"],["Airborne Express - ABX Air","GB"],["Aires - Aerovias de Integracion Regional","4C"],["Airlines of Carriacou","C4"],["Airlines of South Australia","RT"],["Airlink","ND"],["Airmax Airlines","ID"],["Airtours International Airways","VZ"],["Airtran Airways","FL"],["AJT Air International","E9"],["Aklak","6L"],["Alaska Airlines","AS"],["Alaska Central Express - ACE","KO"],["Alaska Seaplane Service","UI"],["Albanian Airlines MAK","LV"],["Alidaunia","D4"],["Alitalia","AZ"],["Alitalia Express","XM"],["Alitalia Team","RD"],["All Nippon Airways","NH"],["Allegro Air","LL"],["Alliance Air","CD"],["Alliance Airlines","3A"],["ALM Antillean Airlines","LM"],["Aloha Airlines","AQ"],["Aloha Island Air","WP"],["Alpi Eagles","E8"],["Alpine Air","5A"],["Alyemen - Airlines of Yemen","DY"],["AMC Aviation","9V"],["America West Airlines","HP"],["American Airlines","AA"],["AmeriJet International","M6"],["Amiri Flight (Abu Dhabi)","MO"],["Angel Airlines","8G"],["Angkor Airlines","TI"],["Ansett Australia","AN"],["Ansett New Zealnad","ZQ"],["AOM French Airlines","IW"],["APA Internacional","7P"],["Ararat Avia","4A"],["Arax Airways","Y5"],["Archana Airways","F5"],["Arctic Circle Air Service","5F"],["Arctic Transportation Services","7S"],["Ariana Afghan Airlines","FG"],["Aries del Sur","D4"],["Arkia Israeli Airlines","IZ"],["Armenian Airlines","R3"],["ARPA - Aerolineas Paraguayas","A8"],["Arrow Air","JW"],["ASA / Delta Connection - Atlantic Southeast Airlines","EV"],["ASERCA - Aeroservicios Carabobo","R7"],["Asian Express Airlines","HJ"],["Asiana Airlines","OZ"],["Aspen Mountain Air","AD"],["Aspiring Air","OI"],["Astanair Kazakstan","A7"],["ATA - American Trans Air","TZ"],["ATA Aerocondor","2B"],["Athabaska Airways","9T"],["Atlant Soyuz Airlines","3G"],["Atlantic Airways","RC"],["Atlantic Coast Airlines","DH"],["Atlas Air","5Y"],["ATRAN - Aviatrans Cargo Airlines","V8"],["Augsburg Airways","IQ"],["Aurigny Air Services","GR"],["Aus Air","NO"],["Austin Express","7V"],["Austral Lineas Aereas","AU"],["Australian Air Express","XM"],["Austrian Airlines","OS"],["Avant Airlines - Linheas Aereas Chilenas","OT"],["Avcom - Aviation Commercial","J6"],["Avensa","VE"],["Avia Express","RX"],["Aviaco","AO"],["Aviacsa","6A"],["Avialeasing","AD"],["Avianca","AV"],["Aviaprima - Sochi Airlines","J5"],["Aviateca","GU"],["Avioimpex Makedonija Airways","M4"],["AVIOR - Aviones de Oriente","3B"],["Aviosarda Airlines","DF"],["Azerbaijan Airlines - AZAL Avia","J2"],["Azzurra Air","ZS"],["B Airways","BF"],["Bahamasair","UP"],["Baikal Airlines","X3"],["Baker Aviation","8Q"],["Balair/CTA Leisure","BB"],["Balkan Bulgarian Airlines","LZ"],["Bangkok Airways","PG"],["Bankair","B4"],["BASE Airlines","5E"],["Bashkirian Airlines - Bashkirskjie Avialinii","V9"],["BAX Global","8W"],["Baxter Aviation","6B"],["Bearskin Airlines","JV"],["Belair Ile de France","BL"],["Belavia","B2"],["Bellair","7G"],["Bellview Airlines","B3"],["Bemidji Airlines","CH"],["Bering Air","8E"],["Berjaya Air","J8"],["Besit Servizi Aerei","B1"],["Bhoja Airlines","B4"],["Big Sky Airlines","GQ"],["Biman Bangladesh Airlines","BG"],["Binter Canarias","NT"],["Binter Mediterraneo","AX"],["Bleu Panorama Airlines","BP"],["Bouraq Indonesia Airlines","BO"],["Braathens","BU"],["Braathens Malmo Aviation","6E"],["Britair","DB"],["Britannia Airways","BY"],["Britannia Airways Deutschland","BN"],["British Airways","BA"],["British International Helicopters","BS"],["British Mediterranean Airways","KJ"],["British Midland Airways","BD"],["British Regional Airlines","TH"],["British World Airlines","VF"],["Brittania Airways Sweden","6B"],["Buffalo Airways","J4"],["Business Express Airlines - BEX","HQ"],["BWIA International Airways","BW"],["CAL - Cargo Airlines","5C"],["Calm Air","MO"],["Camai Air","R9"],["Cameroon Airlines","UY"],["Canada 3000","2T"],["Canadian Airlies International","CP"],["Canarias Regional Air","FW"],["Cape Air","9K"],["Cape Smythe Air Service","6C"],["Cape York Air","NS"],["Capital Cargo International Airlines","PT"],["Cardinal Airlines","NN"],["Cargolux Airlines International","CV"],["Carib Aviation","K7"],["Carribean Air Transport - CLTM Airlines","XC"],["Casino Express","XP"],["Cathay Pacific Airways","CX"],["Cayman Airways","KX"],["Cebu Pacific Air","5J"],["Central Mountain Air","9M"],["Centralafrican Airlines","GC"],["Chalair","M6"],["Chalk's International Airline","OP"],["Challenge Air Cargo","WE"],["Champion Air","MG"],["Changan Airlines","2Z"],["Channel Express","LS"],["Chelal - Chelyabinsk Air Enterprise","H6"],["Chicago Express Airwasy (ATA Connection)","C8"],["China Airlines","CI"],["China Eastern Airlines","MU"],["China National Aviation Corporation - CNAC","F6"],["China Northern Airlines","CJ"],["China Northwest Airlines","WH"],["China Southern Airlines","CZ"],["China Southwest Airlines","SZ"],["China Xinjiang Airlines","XO"],["China Yunnan Airlines","3Q"],["Chitaavia","X7"],["Cimber Air","QI"],["Circle Air Freight","FO"],["Cirrus Airlines","C9"],["City Bird Airlines","H2"],["Cityflyer","FD"],["Cityjet","WX"],["CLA Air Transport","C9"],["Coast Air","BX"],["Coastal Air Transport","DQ"],["Colgan Air","9L"],["Color Air","CA"],["Columbia Pacific Airlines","7C"],["Comair","MN"],["Comair/Delta Connection","OH"],["Compagnie Africaine d'Aviation","E9"],["Compagnie Corse Mediterranee","XK"],["Condor","DE"],["Congo Airlines - CAL","EO"],["Constellation International Airlines","CQ"],["Contact Air","V8"],["Continental Airlines","CO"],["Continental Airways","PC"],["Continental Micronesia","CS"],["COPA Panama","CM"],["Corporate Airlines","3C"],["Corsair","SS"],["Cosmos Air","ZE"],["Country Connection Airlines","XL"],["Coyne Airways","7C"],["Crimea Air","OR"],["Croatia Airlines","OU"],["Cronus Airlines","X5"],["Crossair","LX"],["Crossair Europe","QE"],["CSA Czech Airlines - Ceske Aerolinie","OK"],["Cubana","CU"],["Custom Air Transport","DG"],["Cyprus Airways","CY"],["Daallo Airlines","D3"],["Damania Airways","D2"],["Danish Air Transport","DX"],["DAS - Dirgantara Air Service","AW"],["DAS Air Cargo","SE"],["Debonair Airways","2G"],["Delta Airlines","DL"],["Denim Air","3D"],["Deutsche BA","DI"],["Deutsche Rettungsflugwacht","DV"],["DHL Aero Expreso","DS"],["DHL Airways","ER"],["DHL de Guatemala","Z8"],["DHL International EC","ES"],["Diamond International Airlines","9X"],["Diamond Sakha Airlines","D8"],["Dinar Lineas Aereas","D7"],["Dnieproavia Aviation Company","Z6"],["Dominair - Aerolineas Dominicanas","YU"],["Domodedovo Airlines","E3"],["Donavia","D9"],["Donbass Eastern Ukranian Airlines","7D"],["Dragonair (Hong Kong Dragon Airlines)","KA"],["Dutchbird","5D"],["Eagle Airlines","ZN"],["Eagle Aviation","Y4"],["Eagle Canyon Airlines","FE"],["East Line Airlines","P7"],["Eastland Air - Moores Air Charter","DK"],["Eastwind Airlines","W9"],["Eastwind Airlines - The Bee Line","9W"],["EasyJet Airlines","U2"],["Easyjet Switzerland","BH"],["Ecuatoriana","EU"],["Edelweiss Air","ED"],["Egypt Air","MS"],["El Al Israel Airlines","LY"],["ELK Airways Estonian Aviation - Eesti Lennukompanii","S8"],["Emerald Airways","G3"],["Emery Worldwide Airlines","EB"],["Emirates","EK"],["Empire Airlines","EM"],["Enkor","5Z"],["Equaflight Service","8H"],["ERA Aviation","7H"],["Estonian Air","OV"],["Ethiopian Airlines","ET"],["Euralair International","RN"],["Eureca","F4"],["Eurocypria Airlines","UI"],["Eurofly","GJ"],["Europe Elite","Y6"],["European Air Transport - EAT","QY"],["European Regions Airlines - ERA","EA"],["Euroscot Express Airways","MY"],["Eurowings","EW"],["EVA Air","BR"],["Evergreen International Airlines","EZ"],["Execaire Aviation","MB"],["Executive Express","5W"],["Executive Jet Aviation","1L"],["Expedition Airways","FO"],["Expo Airlines","8D"],["Express One International","EO"],["Falcon Air","IH"],["Falcon Air Express","F2"],["Falcon Express Air Cargo","FC"],["Far Eastern Air Transport","EF"],["Fast Air","UD"],["Faucett","CF"],["Federico II Airways","2D"],["FedEx - Federall Express","FM"],["FedEx - Federall Express","FX"],["Fika Salaama Airlines","HG"],["Fine Airlines","FB"],["Finnair","AY"],["First Air","7F"],["Fischer Air","8F"],["Flandre Air","IX"],["Flight West Airlines","YC"],["Florida West Airlines","RF"],["Fly FTI","FT"],["Flying Colours Airlines","MT"],["Flying Enterprise","F3"],["Forward Air Int'l Airlines","BN"],["Four Star Air Cargo","HK"],["Frontier Airlines","F9"],["Frontier Commuter - ITR Airlines","F9"],["Frontier Flying Service","2F"],["FS Air Service","Y7"],["Fujian Airlines","IV"],["Futura International","FH"],["Garuda Indonesia","GA"],["GB Airways","GT"],["Gemini Air Cargo","GR"],["Gemini Airlines","GR"],["Georgian Airlines","3P"],["Germania","ST"],["Gestair Executive Jet","GP"],["Ghana Airways","GH"],["Gill Airways","9C"],["GMG Airlines","Z5"],["GO Fly","OG"],["Go One Airways","GK"],["Golden Air","DC"],["Golden West Airlines","GW"],["Gomelavia","YD"],["Government of Brunei - His Majesty The Sultan's Flight","UR"],["GP Express Airlines","8G"],["Grant Aviation","GS"],["Great Barrier Airlines","GB"],["Greenlandair - Gronlandsfly","GL"],["Guard Air","FB"],["Gujarat Airways","G8"],["Gulf Air","GF"],["Gulfstream International Airlines","3M"],["Guyana Airways","GY"],["Hageland Aviation Services","H6"],["Hahn Air Businesslines","HR"],["Hainan Airlines","H4"],["Haines Airways","7A"],["Haiti Air International","9F"],["Haiti International Airlines","HG"],["Hapag Lloyd","HF"],["Harbor Airlines","HB"],["Harbour Air","H3"],["Harlequin Air","JH"],["Hawaiian Airlines","HA"],["Hazelton Airlines","ZL"],["Heavylift Cargo Airlines","NP"],["Helenair","2Y"],["Helgoland Airlines","LE"],["Heli Air Monaco","YO"],["Heli Inter","EC"],["Heli Trans","5H"],["Helicopterservice Euro Air","YQ"],["Helijet Airways","JB"],["Helikopter Service","L5"],["Helisul","H9"],["Helisul Taxi Aereo","H9"],["Helisureste","UV"],["Hemus Air","DU"],["Hex'Air","UD"],["Highland Air","HS"],["Highland Airways","8R"],["Hinduja Cargo Services - Lufthansa Cargo India","LF"],["Hokkaido International Airlines - Air Do","HD"],["Horizon Air/Alaska Airlines Commuter","QX"],["Horizon Airlines","YK"],["Iberia","IB"],["Iberostar Airlines","TY"],["Iberworld Airlines","TY"],["ICAR Airlines","C3"],["Icaro","1I"],["Icelandair","FI"],["Iliamna Air taxi","LS"],["Improtex - Imair","IK"],["Impulse Airlines","VQ"],["Indian Airlines","IC"],["Inercontinental Colombia","RS"],["Intensive Air","IM"],["Inter Air Lines","D6"],["Interbrasil Star","Q9"],["International Business Air","U5"],["Iran Air (Iran National Airlines)","IR"],["Iraqi Airways","IA"],["Island Air","G5"],["Island Air","IS"],["Island Airlines","DG"],["Islands Nationair","CN"],["Islandsflug - Icebird Airline","HH"],["Isles of Scilly Skybus","5Y"],["Israir","6H"],["Istanbul Airlines","IL"],["ITA Itapemirim Transportes Aereos","5W"],["Italair","B8"],["JAL Express","JC"],["Japan Air Charter","JZ"],["Japan Air Commuter","3X"],["Japan Air Lines","JL"],["Japan Air System","JD"],["Japan Asia Airways","EG"],["Japan Transocean Air","NU"],["JAT Yugoslav Airlines","JU"],["Jersey European Airways","JY"],["Jet Airways","9W"],["Jet Aviation Business Jets","PP"],["Kaliningrad Avia Entreprise","K8"],["Kampuchea Airlines","KT"],["Karat - Aviacompany Karat","2U"],["Kavminvodyavia","KV"],["KD Air","XC"],["Kendell Airlines (Australia)","KD"],["Kenmore Air","M5"],["Kenn Borek Air","4K"],["Kenya Airways","KQ"],["Keystone Air Services","BZ"],["Khabarovsk Aviation","H8"],["Khors Air","X9"],["Kibris Turkish Airlines - KTHY (Cyprus Turkish Airlines)","YK"],["King Island Airlines","KG"],["Kitty Hawk Air Cargo","KR"],["Kitty hawk International","KR"],["Kiwi International Airlines","KP"],["KLM Cityhopper","WA"],["KLM Exel","XT"],["KLM Royal Dutch Airlines","KL"],["KLM UK","UK"],["Kogalymavia","7K"],["Korean Air","KE"],["Kras Air - Krasnoyarskavia","7B"],["Kronflyg","K4"],["Kuban Airlines","GW"],["Kuwait Airways","KU"],["Kyrgystan Airlines","K2"],["La Ronge Aviation Services - Air Sask Aviation","7W"],["LAB - Lloyd Aereo Boliviano","LB"],["LAB Flying Service - Alaska Airlines Commuter","JF"],["LACSA - Lineasaereas Costarricenses SA","LR"],["LADECO - Linea Aerea Del Cobre","UC"],["LADECO Cargo","UC"],["LAI - Linea Aerea IAACA","KG"],["Laker Airways","6F"],["Laker Airways (Bahamas)","7Z"],["LAM - Linheas Aereas de Mocambique","TM"],["LAN Chile","LA"],["Lao Aviation","QV"],["Laoag International","L7"],["LAPA - Lineas Aereas Privadas Argentinas","MJ"],["Laparkan Airlines","L8"],["Larry's Flying Service","J6"],["Las Vegas Airlines","6G"],["LASER - Lineas Aereas de Servicio Ejecutivo Regional","KZ"],["LASTP","KY"],["Latpass Airlines","QJ"],["Lauda Air","NG"],["Lauda Air Italy","L4"],["Lebanese Air Transport","LQ"],["LGW - Luftfahrt Gesellschaft Walter","HE"],["LIAt - The Carribean Airline","LI"],["Libyan Arab Airlines","LN"],["Link Airways of Australia","XU"],["Lithuanian Airlines","TE"],["LOT Polish Airlines","LO"],["Lotus Air","T2"],["Loveair","4J"],["LTE International Airways","XO"],["LTU International Airways","LT"],["Lufthansa","LH"],["Lufthansa Cargo Airlines","LH"],["Lufthansa Cityline","CL"],["Luxair","LG"],["Lynden Air Cargo","L2"],["Macair Airlines","CC"],["Macedonian Airlines","SX"],["Macedonian Airlines - Makedonski Aviotransport","IN"],["Maersk Air","DM"],["Maersk Air (UK)","VB"],["MAF Australia - Missionary Aviation Fellowship","FS"],["Mafira Air","3A"],["Magadan Airlines","H5"],["Mahfooz Aviation","M2"],["Malev - Hungarian Airlines","MA"],["Malta Air Charter","R5"],["Mandarin Airlines","AE"],["Manx Airlines","JE"],["Mario's Air","M2"],["Maroomba Airlines","KN"],["Martinair","MP"],["MAS - Malaysian Airlines System","MH"],["Mas Air Cargo","MY"],["Maya Island Air","MW"],["Mayan World Airlines","EY"],["MBA Air","CG"],["MDA Airlines","KR"],["MEA - Middle East Airlines","ME"],["Med Airlines","M8"],["Mediterranean Air Service","MG"],["Mercury Air Cargo","BX"],["Meridiana","IG"],["Merpati Nusantara Airlines","MZ"],["Mesa Airlines","YV"],["Metavia Airlines","OW"],["Mexicana","MX"],["Mexicargo","GJ"],["Miami Air International","GL"],["MIAT Mongolian Airlines","OM"],["Midway Airlines","JI"],["Midwest Express Airlines","YX"],["Millair","2Q"],["Minerva Airlines","Q2"],["Miravia","N3"],["MK Airlines","7G"],["MN Aviation","W4"],["MNG Airlines Cargo","MB"],["Modiluft","M9"],["Moldavian Airlines","2M"],["Monarch Airlines","ZB"],["Montenegro Airlines","1I"],["Muk Air","ZR"],["Mustique Airways (Air Saint Vincent)","Q4"],["Naske Air","HC"],["National Airlines","N4"],["National Airways Corporation - NAC","YJ"],["National Jet Systems","NC"],["Nations Air","N5"],["Nationwide Airlines","CE"],["Nature Island Express","XV"],["Necon Air","3Z"],["NEPC Airlines","D5"],["New England Airlines","EJ"],["New York Helicopter","HD"],["NICA - Nicaraguenses de Aviacion","6Y"],["Nice Helicopteres","JX"],["Nigeria Airways","WT"],["Nippon Cargo Airlines","KZ"],["Nordeste - Linhas Aereas regionais","JH"],["Normandie Aviation","ID"],["North American Airlines","XG"],["North Coast Aviation","N9"],["North Vancouver Airliners","VL"],["North Wright Airways","HW"],["Northeast Airlines","NE"],["Northern Air Cargo - NAC","NC"],["Northern Thunderbird Air","4R"],["Northwest Airlines","NW"],["Northwest Airlink/Express Airlines","9E"],["Northwest Airlink/Mesaba Airlines","XJ"],["Northwestern Air","J3"],["Nouvelair Tunesie","BJ"],["Novair - Nova Airlines","1I"],["Novosibirsk Airlines","L8"],["NWT Air - Northwest Territorial Airways","NV"],["O'Connor Airlines - Mount Gambier Airline","UQ"],["Odessa Airlines","5K"],["Olson Air Service","4B"],["OLT - Ostfriesische Lufttransport","OL"],["Olympic Airways","OA"],["Oman Aviation","WY"],["Oman Royal Flight","RS"],["Onur Air","8Q"],["Ord air Charter","RF"],["Orenburg Avia","R2"],["Orient Thai Airlines","OX"],["Origin Pacific Airways","QO"],["Pacific Aiirlines","BL"],["Pacific Airways Corporation - Pacificair","GX"],["Pacific Coastal Airways","8P"],["Pacific Island Aviation","9J"],["Palestinian Airlines","PF"],["Panagra Airways","7E"],["Panair","PV"],["Pantanal - Linhas Aereas Sul Matogrossenses","P8"],["Papillon Grand Canyon Helicopters","HI"],["Par Avion","FP"],["Passaredo Transportes Aereos","Y8"],["Pel Air","QH"],["Pelangi Airways","9P"],["Pem Air","PD"],["Pena Transportes Aereos - PENTA","5P"],["Penair - Peninsula Airways","KS"],["Philippines - Philippine Air Lines","PR"],["PIA - Pakistan International Airlines","PK"],["PINAIR Panamian International","2Q"],["PLUNA","PU"],["Polar Air Cargo","PO"],["Polynesian Airline of Samoa","PH"],["Portugalia","NI"],["Precision Air Services","PW"],["Premiar","DK"],["Premier Trans Aire","P3"],["President Airlines","TO"],["Pro Air","P9"],["Pro Mech Air","Z3"],["Proteus Air System","YS"],["Provincial Airlines","AG"],["Pulkovo Avia","Z8"],["Qantas","QF"],["Qatar Airways","QR"],["Queen Air","7Q"],["Qwestair","QD"],["RAS Fluggesellschaft","RW"],["Redwing Airways","RX"],["Reeve Aleutian Airways - RAA","RV"],["Region Air","7S"],["Regional Air","QT"],["Regional Airlines","FN"],["Regional Airlines","VM"],["Regional Lineas Aereas","XG"],["Regionnair","RH"],["Reguljair","R8"],["Reno Air","QQ"],["Rheintalflug","WE"],["Riga Airlines - RiAir","GV"],["Rio Sul","SL"],["ROAN Air","Q3"],["Romavia","WQ"],["Roots Air","6J"],["Rover Airways International","5R"],["Royal Air Cambodge","VJ"],["Royal Air Maroc","AT"],["Royal Airlines","QN"],["Royal Brunei Airlines","BI"],["Royal Jordanian","RJ"],["Royal Nepal Airlines","RA"],["Royal Tongan Airlines ( Friendly Island Airways)","WR"],["Rusavia Int'l Aviatransport","2Q"],["Ryan International Airlines","1I"],["Ryanair","FR"],["SA Airlink - Midlands Aviation","4Z"],["SA Alliance","Y2"],["Sabena","SN"],["Sabre Airways","TJ"],["SAETA - Sociedad Ecuatoriana de Aereos","EH"],["Safair","FA"],["Sahara Airlines","S2"],["Saint Barth Commuter","PV"],["Sakha Avia","K7"],["Sakhalinskie Aviatrassy - SAT","HZ"],["SAM - Sociedad Aeonautica de Medellin","MM"],["SAM - Sociedad Aeronautica de Medellin","MM"],["Samara Airlines","E5"],["Samoa Air","SE"],["SAN - Servicios Aereos Nationales","WB"],["San Air Company","S3"],["SANSA - Servicios Aereos Nacionales SA","RZ"],["Santa Barbara Airlines","BJ"],["SAS - Scandinavian Airlines System","SK"],["SATA Air Acores","SP"],["SATA International","S4"],["Saudi Arabian Airlines","SV"],["Sayakhat","W7"],["Scenic Air","3L"],["Scenic Airlines","YR"],["Schreiner Airways","AW"],["Seaborne Aviation","BB"],["Sempati Air Transport","SG"],["Servivensa - Empresa Servicios Avensa SA","VC"],["Shaheen Air International","NL"],["Shanghai Airlines","FM"],["Shanxi Airlines","8C"],["Shenzen Airlines","4G"],["Shepparton Airlines","OB"],["Shorouk Air","7Q"],["Shunshine Express Airlines","CQ"],["Shuswap Flight Centre","3S"],["Shuttle America","S5"],["Sibaviatrans","5M"],["Siberia Airlines","S7"],["Sichuan Airlines","3U"],["Sierra National Airlines","LJ"],["Sierra Pacific Airlines","SI"],["Silkair","MI"],["Singapore Airlines","SQ"],["SK Air","S9"],["Skargardsflyg","5Q"],["Skippers Aviation","SY"],["Sky Cabs","2E"],["Sky Trek International Airlines","1I"],["Skyking","RU"],["Skymark Airlines","BC"],["Skytrans","NP"],["Skyward Aviation","K9"],["Skyway Airlines / Midwest Express Connection","AL"],["Skyways","JZ"],["Skywest Airlines","OO"],["Skywest Airlines","YT"],["Slovak Airlines - Slovenske Aerolinie","6Q"],["Sobelair","Q7"],["Solomon Airlines","IE"],["South African Airways - SAA","SA"],["South African Express Airways","YB"],["SouthCentral Air","XE"],["Southern Winds","A4"],["Southwest Airlines","WN"],["Spanair","JK"],["Special Cargo Airlines","C7"],["Spirit Airlines","NK"],["STAF - Servicios de Transportes Aereos Fueguino","FS"],["Star Airlines","2R"],["Starwelt Airways","2N"],["State Transport Company of Russia","R4"],["Suckling Airways","CB"],["Sudan Airways","SD"],["Sun Air","BV"],["Sun Air of Scandinavia","EZ"],["Sun Country Airlines","SY"],["Sun Express","XQ"],["Sunflower Airlines","PI"],["Sunjet International Airlines","JX"],["Sunrise Airlines","OQ"],["Sunworld International Airways","SM"],["Superior Aviation","AB"],["Surinam Airways / SLM ","PY"],["Svea Flyg","SI"],["Swazi Airlink","ZC"],["Swedeways Air Lines","HJ"],["Swiss Wings","RQ"],["Swissair","SR"],["Syrianair - Syrian Arab Airlines","RB"],["TAAG - Linhas Aereas de Angola - Angola Airlines","DT"],["TACA International Airlines","TA"],["TACV - Cabo Verde Airlines","VR"],["TAESA - Transportes Aereos Ejecutivos SA","GD"],["TAG Aviation","FP"],["TAM - Transportes Aereos Meridionais","JJ"],["TAM - Transportes Aereos Regionais","KK"],["TAM - Travaux Aeriens de Madagascar","OF"],["TAME - Transportes Aereos Militares Ecuatoriana","EQ"],["TAMPA Colombia","QT"],["TAN - Transportes Aereos Neuquen","T8"],["Tanana Air Services","4E"],["TAP Air Portugal","TP"],["Taquan Air Service","K3"],["TAROM - Transporturile Aerienne Romane","RQ"],["Tasawi Air Service","9X"],["Tashkent Aircraft Production Corporation","PQ"],["Tatra Air","QS"],["TAVAJ - Transportes Aereos Regulares","4U"],["Tavrey Aircompany","T6"],["Teddy Air","ZJ"],["Tempelhoff Express Airlines - TEX","FC"],["Tesis","UZ"],["Thai Air Cargo","2Y"],["Thai Airways International","TG"],["TMA - Trans Mediterranean Airlines","TL"],["Tolair Services","TI"],["Tower Air","FF"],["Trade Winds Airlines","WI"],["Trans Air","P6"],["Trans America Peru","ES"],["Trans Asian Airlines","T7"],["Trans European Airlines","UE"],["Trans International Express","5B"],["Trans States Airlines","9N"],["Trans Travel Airlines - TTA","6N"],["Trans World Airlines - TWA","TW"],["Transaero Airlines","UN"],["Transasia Airways","GE"],["Transavia Airlines","HV"],["TransAvia Export","AL"],["Transbrasil","TR"],["Transcaraibes Air  International","DZ"],["Transeast Airlines","T4"],["Transmeridian Airlines","T9"],["Transmile Air Services","TH"],["Transstate Airlines","BH"],["Travelair","U3"],["Tropic Air","PM"],["Tunisair","TU"],["Tunisinter","UG"],["Turanair","3T"],["Turkish Airlines","TK"],["Turkmenistan Airlines - Turkmenhavayollari","T5"],["Turks and Caicos Airways","QW"],["Turtle Airways","KT"],["Tyrolean Airways","VO"],["Tyumen Airlines","7M"],["TyumenAviaTrans","P2"],["U Land Airlines","WI"],["Uganda Airlines","QU"],["Ukraine International Airlines","PS"],["UNA - Southern Independent Air Company","F2"],["UNI Air","B7"],["United Airlines","UA"],["United Express / Great Lakes Airlines","ZK"],["United Express/Air Wisconsin","ZW"],["United Express/Atlantic Coast Airlines","DH"],["United Express/Trans States Airlines","9N"],["United Express/United Feeder Services","U2"],["Universal Airways","UV"],["UPS - United Parcel Service","5X"],["Ural Airlines - Uralskie Avialinii","U6"],["US Airways","US"],["US Airways Express","US"],["US Airways Express/Air Midwest","ZV"],["US Airways Express/Allegheny Commuter Airlines","US"],["US Airways Express/Chautauqua Airlines","US"],["US Airways Express/Piedmont Airlines","US"],["US Airways Shuttle","TB"],["USA Jet Airlines","U7"],["Uzbekistan Airways","HY"],["V-Air - Varmlandsflyg","T9"],["Vanguard Airlines","NJ"],["Varig","RG"],["VASP","VP"],["VIA - Air VIA Bulgarian Airways","VL"],["Vieques Air Link","VI"],["Vietnam Airlines","VN"],["Vip Air","9V"],["Virgin Atlantic","VS"],["Virgin Express","TV"],["Viva Air","FV"],["Vladivostok Air","XF"],["VLM - Vlaamse Luchtvaart Maatschappij","VG"],["Vnukovo Airlines","V5"],["Volare Air transport","OP"],["Volare Airlines","8D"],["Volare Ukraine","F7"],["Volga Airlines","G6"],["Volga Dnepr Airlines","VI"],["Voronezh Avia","ZT"],["Voyageur Airways","4V"],["Wairapa Airlines - Pacific Midland Airlines","2W"],["Warbelow's Air Ventures","4W"],["Wasaya Airways","WG"],["Welcome Air","2W"],["West Coast Air","8O"],["West Isle Air","7Y"],["Westair","OE"],["Western Air Freight","WZ"],["Western Airlines","EM"],["Westjet Airlines","M3"],["Whyalla Airlines","WW"],["Wideroe - Wideroe's Flyveselskap","WF"],["Winair - Windward Island Airways International","WM"],["Wings of Alaska","K5"],["Winnport Air Cargo","KN"],["World Airways","WO"],["Wright Air Service","8V"],["Xiamen Airlines","MF"],["Yanda Airlines","ST"],["Yangon Airways","HK"],["Yemenia - Yemen Airways","IY"],["Yute Air Alaska","4Y"],["Zimbabwe Express Airlines","Z7"],["Zimex Aviation","C4"]];console.log(l);
```

Comment: Ran out of characters so description is down here: 1) Copy-Paste, 2) Notepad++ search and replace with `regex` to insert `'`,`[`, `]` and the rest of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not clear but if I get you, you just need to split the String on the last space, so this would do it

```
var array = ["40 Mile Air Q5",
        "AB Airlines 7L",
        "ABSA Cargo - Aerolinhas Breseleiras SA M3",
        "AccessAir ZA",
        "ACES Colombia VX"];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var lastIndex = array[i].lastIndexOf(' ');
    array[i] = [ array[i].substr(0, lastIndex), array[i].substr(lastIndex) ];
}
```

Simply finding the last occurence and using a substring to split on two cells.